# OpenCV: Make a Difference-of-Gaussian

Tags: opencv

Is there a simple way of making DoG kernel to filter a image. I know it is possible to generate the kernels manually and then substract them from each other, but isn't there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to create the analytic formula for your kernel, with the needed parameters, and calculate the position of every pixel inside.

```
getDoG(i,j, sigma1Big, sigma2Big, sigma1Small, sigma2small, 
                            rotationBig, rotationSmall, kernelSize, ...);
```

Do not ask me for the formula :)

But the easiest way is to make two kernels with the correct parameters and subtract them.

**Do not forget** to normalize the kernel (shift the values so that the sum of all kernel values is 1)

Comment: Sure, but I think this is to cumbersome, when I have a opencv library available. I manage to overcome this problem by generating to seperable kernels and multiply them together.